# Intent na fragment activity Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Como fazer para abrir uma nova tela ou link através do intent na fragment activity?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Vejam que tem um botão no final como fazer com que ele abra um link?

Comment: Vc quer abrir o navegador ou abrir o site dentro do aplicativo com a webView?

Comment: Desejo abrir no navegador!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, primeiro você deve adicionar a permissão de internet no AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Depois você pode chamar a Intent passando a URI

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
```